# I am not able to figure out what does ls -alF give in unix?

Tags: unix

Below is what i get when i run ls -alF in the ftp directory:-

-rw-r--r-- 1 ssrftp ssssftp 3135 May 16 17:00 WAQ12.txt

Can someone explain me what are the different parameters ?

like -rw-r--r-- is permission what is 1 =? ssrftp =? ssssftp =? etc

Comment: The 1 is the hard link count to the file. ( See https://askubuntu.com/questions/19510/what-does-the-second-column-in-the-output-of-ls-n-mean ) ssrftp is the owner user of the file, ssssftp is the owner group of the file. Here we normally thank the people who help us...

Answer (score 5):

The `-a` option will show all hidden files and directories (Those who start with ."

The `-l` options shows the permissions, owner, group and more information

Finally the `-F` classify the results in files and folders. Adding a "/" at the end of the row for each folder. In case the file is a binary it will put a different character. It's a parameter to make things more visual when you have a lot of files and directories with different extensions.

- "@" Is shown when a file is a symbolic link
- "*" When is executable
- "/" Means that is a directory
- "|" for pipes.

etc..

You can use `man ls` in order to know more parameters of ls